# Android (API 26) take full picture

Tags: android, android-camera

I use to get a picture this simple code, it work but the size of the pictures are too small.

How can i get from the camera a better quality pictures?

```
private void captureImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == FragmentActivity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            createImagePath();

            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            File file = new File(savedFileUri.getPath());

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "FileNotFoundException " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "IOException " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath

Comment: Yes, i have see!
The follow note was important !!!!
Note: We are using getUriForFile(Context, String, File) which returns a content:// URI. For more recent apps targeting Android 7.0 (API level 24) and higher, passing a file:// URI across a package boundary causes a FileUriExposedException. Therefore, we now present a more generic way of storing images using a FileProvider.                                                                       THANX for help